# How to use SDelete to wipe out an entire directory and all its contents

Tags: windows-10

I've downloaded the Microsoft Sys-internals [SDelete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) to safely wipe out files from a laptop.

Based on the documentation and the help, the `-s` option allows to "Recurse subdirectories" and the `-r` to "remove read-only attribute". So I use it like this, from an *administrator* prompt:

```
sdelete -s -r c:\Users\guest\Documents
```

But I always get *"Error deleting path/to/directory: The directory is not empty"*.

Is there a solution that does not involve calling a command for each subdirectory in the tree? I have also tried `sdelete64` with the same result. I don't care about files that can't be deleted because they're in use or whatever, just as many as possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on using SDelete to directly wipe out a directory tree. Instead, I used the following approach to delete an entire user's data (after backup):

1 - Create a new local administrator user, without a Microsoft account (e.g. newadmin)

2 - Login as the other user (e.g. myuser) and sign-out (top left icon after clicking the start button)

3 - Login as newadmin again and on settings, select myuser and remove account, choosing to delete all data

4 - Pretty much all data is gone at this point, but to be thorough go to Windows Explorer and delete the entire "\Users\myuser" folder. Then empty the recycle bin.

5 - There should be now plenty of free space reported by Windows 10. We can now use *sdelete* to zero that free space which may contain data, as follows, through an *administrator* prompt:

```
sdelete64 -z c:
```

I left the default one pass, because it's sufficient for my needs and the disk is SSD anyway.

If you just want to delete a random folder then just perform the last step after standard Windows deletion.

By the way I noticed that on Windows 10, one can also go to "Settings > Recovery > Reset this PC" and along the wizard choose "Remove files and clean the drive" which is supposed to do a better job at erasing files when passing the PC along, than the standard reset.

Answer (score 5):

There may be some read-only files or directories in the specified folder tree.

See if adding the `-r` switch helps.

```
sdelete -s -r c:\Users\guest\Documents
```

If that doesn't help, post the entire output for further diagnosis.

## **Important Note**

The command-line arguments listed at the Microsoft site **is outdated**.

Here are the **latest** command-line arguments. As of this post, the latest SDelete version is `v2.02`

```
SDelete v2.02 - Secure file delete
Copyright (C) 1999-2018 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

usage: sdelete [-p passes] [-r] [-s] [-q] <file or directory> [...]
       sdelete [-p passes] [-z|-c [percent free]] <drive letter [...]>
       sdelete [-p passes] [-z|-c] <physical disk number>

   -c         Clean free space. Specify an option amount of space
              to leave free for use by a running system.
   -p         Specifies number of overwrite passes (default is 1)
   -r         Remove Read-Only attribute
   -s         Recurse subdirectories
   -z         Zero free space (good for virtual disk optimization)
   -nobanner  Do not display the startup banner and copyright message.
```

---

### **Outdated list of CL arguments ↓**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have actually been using `-r` most of the time, but it wasn't consistent with the documentation and I couldn't remember where I got it from, so I left it out the post, but will update it now. Also, the output is way too large, that's why I only showed the error names, they just repeat.

Comment: If you have privacy concerns, you can obfuscate the file names in the output and upload the screenshot or text online. The error messages are helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: But I've already posted the message, it's "Error deleting xxx: The directory is not empty". Where xxx are the full path to the subdirectories inside the folder, so there are a lot of those repeated messages. I'd post a screen-shot of the text but this is on another machine and the browser there stopped working probably because I've deleted some essential files on my home directory already (probably `appdata` or something).

Comment: It's possible that some files are in use by programs, or locked down by NTFS permissions.

Comment: True, those do show up with a message saying they're in use or whatever, I don't care about them. I have like text or image files at various levels in the tree and they're not in use and not being deleted. A few have been deleted, seems very random, but most are not. So this recursion feature seems a bit useless.

Answer (score 2):

**Use ***
This worked for me:

1. In PowerShell, change into directory `cd SomeDir`
2. `sdelete -s *`
3. `cd ..`
4. `remove-item -force -recurse SomeDir`